# Microsoft Word 2013 hangs on open if server is off

Tags: windows-server-2003

A member server that used to be a DC on our network was powered down about a week ago and now some workstations are experiencing problems with Microsoft Word.
When opening Word it will hang for about 40 seconds and then be fine after that. The workstations are not referencing any shared folders or printers on the server in question. However, if I turn the server back on the problem goes away.
I have tried the following:
Disconnected all mapped drives on the workstation - even though they were not pointing to shares on the old server.
Removed all printers (local and network) from the workstation.
Uninstalled MS Office and reinstalled it, adding all updates.

The problem does not occur when starting Word in safe mode.
When starting Word w/o addins (eg: cmd>winword /a) it will be ok for a couple of seconds and then freeze for 20 or 30 seconds.
I hate to ask for help but I've had it.

Workstations are running Windows 7.
Our DC's are 2008r2 and 2016.
The server in question is 2k3 and used to be a DC and served shared folders and printers etc.

Comment: Run SysInternals procmon on the workstation when you load Word, look to see if there is any attempt to open `\\server\whatever` - it might be something like previously opened documents, or a default template path or other non-obvious reference. If the server was a DC, was it also a DNS server, and does the workstation have working DNS when it's powered off?

Comment: Yes, i'm seeing a bunch of \\<servername>\IPC$, FileSystemControl, Closefile, CreateFile entries. Looks like it is trying to create a dictionary file on a shared folder on that server. Thank you!!! Hopefully I will be able to figure it out now.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure no reditected folder are on that server, and that office is not set to save temporary file there

I would do a fresh office reinstall with the media kit, not any homemade custom setup with preanswer or defined options.